# is <marquee> supported in html5?

Tags: html, css

Is `marquee` element supported in ***Html 5*** ? if not, how could we give that effect (design) by **Css 3** coding. I mean scrolling text one side to another side, etc etc.
Some browsers still supports marquee element. But when I google it. Some sites are saying that it is not supported by html 5. So what is its alternative options in css 3.

Comment: take a look at https://codepen.io/Jofiman/pen/JoGXMv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### From MDN

The HTML `<marquee>` element is used to insert a scrolling area of text. You can control what happens when the text reaches the edges of its content area using its attributes.

> The  element is obsolete and must not be used. While some browsers still support it, it's not required.

#### Marquee in CSS3

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.marquee {
  height: 25px;
  width: 420px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div>
    <span>You spin me right round, baby. Like a record, baby.</span>
    <span>You spin me right round, baby. Like a record, baby.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use css keyframes for making marquee effect

```
 <div class="marquee">
      <div>
        <span>This is marquee text...done with css keyframes without using marquee tag</span>
      <span>This is marquee text...done with css keyframes without using marquee tag</span>
    </div>



body { margin: 20px; }

.marquee {
  height: 25px;
  width: 600px;

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;

  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;

  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The element has been deprecated and should no longer be used. CSS or JavaScript can be used to create similar effects. We can now use the following CSS3 properties like marquee-play-count, marquee-style, overflow-style, marquee-direction and marquee-speed.